# Go Golang to serve a specific html file

Tags: http, go

```
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))
```

Serves the `html` file in static directory.

Is there any way in Go that we can specify the `html` file to serve?

Something like `render_template` in `Flask`

I want to do something like:

```
http.Handle("/hello", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static/hello.html")))
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Maybe using a [custom `http.HandlerFunc`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc) would be easier:

Except in your case, your func would be the [`http.ServeFile`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile) one, for serving just one file.

See for instance "[Go Web Applications: Serving Static Files](http://jessekallhoff.com/2013/04/14/serving-static-content-from-go/)":

> <del>Add the following below your home handler</del> (see below):

```
http.HandleFunc("/static/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   // do NOT do this. (see below)
    http.ServeFile(w, r, r.URL.Path[1:])
})
```

> This is using the `net/http` package’s ServeFile function to serve our content.
> Effectively anything that makes a request starting with the `/static/` path will be handled by this function.
> One thing I found I had to do in order for the request to be handled correctly was trim the leading ‘/’ using:

```
r.URL.Path[1:]
```

Actually, do not do that.
This won't be possible in Go 1.6, as [sztanpet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5832/sztanpet) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945538/go-golang-to-serve-a-specific-html-file/25945832?noredirect=1#comment57919326_25945832), with [commit 9b67a5d](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/9b67a5de79af56541c48c95c6d7ddc8630e1d0dc):

> If the provided file or directory name is a relative path, it is
> interpreted relative to the current directory and **may ascend to parent
> directories**.
> If the provided name is constructed from user input, it should be sanitized before calling `ServeFile`.
> As a precaution, `ServeFile` will reject requests where `r.URL.Path` contains a "`..`" path element.

That will protect against the following "url":

```
/../file
/..
/../
/../foo
/..\\foo
/file/a
/file/a..
/file/a/..
/file/a\\..
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use `http.StripPrefix`

Like this:

```
http.Handle("/hello/", http.StripPrefix("/hello/",http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I missed something here, but after a lot of confused searching, I put this together:

...

```
func downloadHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        r.ParseForm()
        StoredAs := r.Form.Get("StoredAs") // file name
        data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("files/"+StoredAs)
        if err != nil { fmt.Fprint(w, err) }
        http.ServeContent(w, r, StoredAs, time.Now(),   bytes.NewReader(data))
}
```

...

Where downloadHandler is invoked as part of a simple upload and download server:

```
func main() {
              http.HandleFunc("/upload", uploadHandler)
              http.HandleFunc("/download", downloadHandler)
              http.ListenAndServe(":3001", nil)
}
```

Works fine with Firefox and Chrome. Doesn't even need a file type.

Comment: What happens if the StoredAs param contains "../../mysecrets ?

Comment: I don't know. What happens?

Comment: A directory traversal attack

Comment: always a good idea to treat URIs and user input as malicious and trying to penetrate your server. never trust those inputs. sanitize it!